# class function to remove value from array list object

Tags: python, list, object, arraylist

I am trying to write a class function that removes the first occurence of e (int number) from my array list and for it to return True but if no occurence then return false without adjustment to my array list.

```
def removeVal(self, e):
    A = self.inArray
    for x in A:
        i+=1
        if x == e:
            A.remove(i)
            self.inArray = A
            return True
        return False

list = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
list.removeVal(2)
print(list)

class ArrayList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inArray = []
        self.count = 0
        
    def get(self, i):
        return self.inArray[i]

    def set(self, i, e):
        self.inArray[i] = e

    def length(self):
        return self.count

def isIn(A, k): # similar to this
#    for i in range(len(A)):
#        if A[i] == k:
#            return True
#    return False
```

Comment: And what exactly does not work / is the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your intention, can you please elaborate. By a class function do you mean a method inside a python object?

Comment: looks like you're trying to modify a list while iterating through it, which is problematic.

Comment: There is no class in your code. `A = self.inArray` is meaningless without it

Comment: You're trying to program Python as though it was Java. Even if you wanted setters and getters, this isn't how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if e is in the list. list.remove(x) removes the first occurence of x in the list.

You can switch out 'yourlist' with the list you are using.

```
def removeVal(self, e):
    if e in yourlist:
        yourlist.remove(e)
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: `yourList` doesn't even exist in this code snippet. This cannot possibly run

Comment: it wasn't clear what list he wanted to use, since he didn't specify the attributes of the class. Therefore I said he can switch out 'yourlist' with the list he wishes to use.

Comment: Then don't answer. It can't be an answer if you don't even know what they're asking

Comment: I am trying to replicate this without using "if e in list" for example something similar to (see end of original post)

Comment: Not to mention that this code really doesn't make sense. Why would you return a bool to removing items from a list? If it was in the list, you've now made sure it's not, so what does `True` mean?

Comment: because that is what the question asks for:) @roganjosh

Comment: I think you need to challenge that assumption. This looks like an XY problem